# Hackerrank - Solving Palindrom Index Solution

Tags: java, algorithm, logic, reverse, palindrome

**Problem:**

Given a string of lower case letters in the range ascii[a-z], identify the index of character to be removed to change the string into a palindrome. If the string cannot be converted to palindrome or is already a palindrome just return -1 else return index of the character to be removed.

**My Solution:**

```
public static int palindromeIndex(String s) {

    if(p(s)){
        return -1;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){

        sb.deleteCharAt(i);
        if(p(sb.toString())){
            return i;
        }
        sb.insert(i,s.charAt(i));
    }


    return -1;

}

private static boolean p(String s){

    for(int i=0; i<s.length()/2; i++){
        if(s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(s.length() - i - 1)){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

It is failing for one or all below test cases (unable to determine for which one) according to hackerrank:

1. quyjjdcgsvvsgcdjjyq
2. hgygsvlfwcwnswtuhmyaljkqlqjjqlqkjlaymhutwsnwcflvsgygh
3. fgnfnidynhxebxxxfmxixhsruldhsaobhlcggchboashdlurshxixmfxxxbexhnydinfngf
4. bsyhvwfuesumsehmytqioswvpcbxyolapfywdxeacyuruybhbwxjmrrmjxwbhbyuruycaexdwyfpaloyxbcpwsoiqtymhesmuseufwvhysb
5. fvyqxqxynewuebtcuqdwyetyqqisappmunmnldmkttkmdlnmnumppasiqyteywdquctbeuwenyxqxqyvf
6. mmbiefhflbeckaecprwfgmqlydfroxrblulpasumubqhhbvlqpixvvxipqlvbhqbumusaplulbrxorfdylqmgfwrpceakceblfhfeibmm
7. tpqknkmbgasitnwqrqasvolmevkasccsakvemlosaqrqwntisagbmknkqpt
8. lhrxvssvxrhl
9. prcoitfiptvcxrvoalqmfpnqyhrubxspplrftomfehbbhefmotfrlppsxburhyqnpfmqlaorxcvtpiftiocrp
10. kjowoemiduaaxasnqghxbxkiccikxbxhgqnsaxaaudimeowojk

**My Output:**

1. 1
2. 8
3. 33
4. 23
5. 24
6. 43
7. 20
8. -1
9. 14
10. -1

I debugged to code locally, and according to my understanding, this test case is working fine. Please help me out understating, what is wrong with the code.

**Note:** I can do it with other alternative ways (more simpler ways), solutions are available online, but i am trying to understand, what is wrong with my piece of java code. Thanks.

Comment: You can do this in a simpler way: modify the palindromicity test so that it counts mismatches when scanning both ways, and tolerates exactly one (in you can use the index for this purpose).

Comment: your code passed the submission! ..but didn't pass test case 7,12,14 due to: timeout! so it looks "correct"! but could be "more efficient"! ;)

Comment: try a "linear" algorithm in favor to a "quadratic" one... ( -> [discussions](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/palindrome-index/forum))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code times out on some test cases. It is not very efficient to try to delete each character and then check whether that is a palindrome.

By first checking whether the original string is a palindrome you can find the spot where it fails, which leaves you with just 2 possibilities for deletion. So you would only need to try those two. Moreover, you don't actually have to *perform* the deletion. You can just skip the concerned character and continue the palindrome check by skipping the corresponding index.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
    public static int palindromeIndex(String s) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = s.length() - 1;
        while (start < end && s.charAt(start) == s.charAt(end)) {
            start++;
            end--;
        }
        if (start >= end) return -1; // already a palindrome
        // We need to delete here
        if (isPalindrome(s, start + 1, end)) return start;
        if (isPalindrome(s, start, end - 1)) return end;
        return -1;
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String s, int start, int end) {
        while (start < end && s.charAt(start) == s.charAt(end)) {
            start++;
            end--;
        }
        return start >= end;        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the great algorithm! But I guess the problem is in HakerRank testing system, not in execution time. For example see the case 6:

s = mmbiefhflbeckaecprwfgmqlydfroxrblulpasumubq-hh-bvlqpixvvxipqlvbhqbumusaplulbrxorfdylqmgfwrpceakceblfhfeibmm

Your code gives the answer 44, while topic-starter answer is 43 - and both are correct (I emphasise those letters with '-'). Task descriptions says that "in case of more than one solution any will do". _But it's not true_: to see this I hard-code the answer 43 for this case, and the test fails, although when I hard-code 44 it passes.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this, danek. I added `if (s.compareTo( "mmbiefhflbeckaecprwfgmqlydfroxrblulpasumubqhhbvlqpixvvxipqlvbhqbumusaplulbrxorfdylqmgfwrpceakceblfhfeibmm") == 0) return 43;` to the top of my function and the solution was accepted by HackerRank. I also submitted a version with a `return start-1` when possible, which would also cover this case: `if (isPalindrome(s, start + 1, end)) {
            if (start > 0 && s.charAt(start) == s.charAt(start-1)) return start - 1;
            return start;
        }`. This also was accepted by HackerRank.